# Vector magnitude and complex numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

If a vector $v= (1-\imath, 1+\imath)$ then the $\|v\|$ is equal to $\sqrt{(1-\imath)^2 + (1+\imath)^2}$ = $\sqrt{2+2i^2}$ = $\sqrt{2-2(-1)} = 0$?

Comment: Recall that if, for example $x \in \mathbb{C}^2$ $||x|| = \sqrt{<x,x>} =  \sqrt{x_1\bar{x_1} + x_2\bar{x_2}}$ in other words like ellya said you need to conjugate the second component of your vector

Answer (score 1):

For complex vectors, the norm is define as follows:

$\|(z_1,z_2)\|=\sqrt{z_1\overline{z_1}+z_2\overline{z_2}}$

So here we have:

$\|(1-i,1+i)\|=\sqrt{(1+i)(1-i)+(1+i)(1-i)}=\sqrt{2+2}=\sqrt 4=2$